# how to use selModel for dynamic grid in extjs3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am using xml for column in my grid. I need a checkbox at begning of a row, When I am designing column in grid I am getting but I am not sure how to do in dynamic.

I will share here what I did.
I place

`var checkBoxSelMod = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();`

Then  I am using `selModel : checkBoxSelMod,` in grid and in column

```
columns: [
checkBoxSelMod,
{header: " Doctor Name ", dataIndex: 'doctor_name', width: 249 },
{header: " Hospital Name ", dataIndex: 'hospital_name', width: 249 }
]
});
```

I wanted to make dynamic. What I need to add in my xml and how to use this in code. Thanks

Comment: Give the code where you making dynamic column.